# Adding oil/fat to bread dough

Tags: bread, dough

I make bread by mixing whole wheat and white flours 50-50, yeast and water, let it rise 24 hrs, shape the dough and roll it in flour to get some semblance of final shape and let it sit for 2 more hours, then bake it for an hour.

I love the bread but I wonder if adding olive oil to the dough would make it more pleasantly moist. Before I experiment in practice, what results can I expect by adding (a few tablespoons of) olive oil to bread dough?

Comment: MY bread recipe is 350ml water. 50g olive oil, 30g honey, 400g strong flour, 15g yeast, 15g salt.  I think it's quite nice :-)

Answer (score 5):

It will have less of an open crumb but will be softer and more moist.

Answer (score 2):

**You will make pizza crust.**

> Overview: Homemade Pizza Dough Ingredients All pizza dough starts with
> the same basic ingredients: flour, yeast, water, salt, and olive oil.
> https://sallysbakingaddiction.com/homemade-pizza-crust-recipe/

My daughter makes a great pizza dough.  It is just bread dough with oil.  Plus she talks to it.  I encourage you to make pizza crust, and make a delicious pizza out of it.

Comment: A recipe is more than just the ingredients list.  You also have proportions and technique.  Those ingredients could make focaccia, chiabata or even loaf of bread : https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/17804/olive-oil-bread/

Comment: I love the "she talks to it" part!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Always good to give your dough a nice little pat too, after turning it out from the first rising.